# JAVAFX ListView chatting

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I need to insert values in list view in one by one like chatting.
now my code is

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> messageList;    

private ObservableList<String> messages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();    

messageList.setItems(messages);
```

Comment: use `messages.add(String)` in a iterator

Comment: I am already check with this i have a design inside this list view i need to add that design and insert values one by one.  how to add design inside list view and how to add values in one by one?

Comment: You want to add a List to your `ListView` or update the `ObservableList` by adding new items ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be similar to what you are asking.

> Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChatApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Controller:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private ListView lvChatWindow;
    @FXML private TextField tfUser1, tfUser2;

    ObservableList<String> chatMessages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();//create observablelist for listview


    //Method use to handle button press that submits the 1st user's text to the listview.
    @FXML
    private void handleUser1SubmitMessage(ActionEvent event) {
        chatMessages.add("User 1: " + tfUser1.getText());//get 1st user's text from his/her textfield and add message to observablelist
        tfUser1.setText("");//clear 1st user's textfield
    }

    //Method use to handle button press that submits the 2nd user's text to the listview.
    @FXML
    private void handleUser2SubmitMessage(ActionEvent event) {
        chatMessages.add("User 2: " + tfUser2.getText());//get 2nd user's text from his/her textfield and add message to observablelist
        tfUser2.setText("");//clear 2nd user's textfield
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        lvChatWindow.setItems(chatMessages);//attach the observablelist to the listview
    }      
}
```

> FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="349.0" prefWidth="549.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" fx:controller="chatapp.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="bntUser1Send" layoutX="99.0" layoutY="299.0" onAction="#handleUser1SubmitMessage" text="send message user1" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <Button fx:id="btnUser2Send" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="299.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleUser2SubmitMessage" text="send message user2" />
      <ListView fx:id="lvChatWindow" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="29.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="419.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="tfUser1" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="258.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="239.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="tfUser2" layoutX="293.0" layoutY="258.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="239.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image]

This app simulates two different users sending messages to one listview. Similar to a chat. More comments in Controller

Comment: Very nice!. . .Although there is no need to implement `Initializable` here . You can just add `@FXML public void initialize() {.. } `