# Dynamically Updating a ListView from a TextField (JavaFX)

Tags: java, string, listview, javafx

I'm trying to apply names(strings) into a ListView within JavaFX using a simple event handler on a button, receiving input from TextFields. All the fields seem to be working and correct, it just doesnt update into the list view

```
    private ListView<String> manifestList;
    manifestList = new ListView<>();
    manifestList.setId("List");
    manifestList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
```

ListView add method:

```
   public void addtoList(String manifestlist){
    manifestList.getItems().add(manifestlist);
   }
```

For loop which generates text boxes for input (I have preset it to name1, name2 etc to test it)

```
    for( i = 0;i < editname.length;i++){
    editname[i] = new TextField("Name" + i);    
    }
```

Button handler to add the text from textfields to the listview (There is 16 text boxes)

```
 Button add = new Button("add");

    add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){

            for(i=0; i<16; i++){
            test.addtoList(editname[i].getText());
        }       
    }
});
```

test is the variable name  for the class I am calling the add method from, which the list view is in. The button which is calling the add method, is in a different scene/class.

I can't quite figure out what's going wrong here, i've printed the value of the textfields to console and they print fine - however they dont update into the ListView.

I've tried using the add method with a preset string in the list view and that is added fine.

Any help/tips would be great thanks.

Comment: What is `test`? It would be much easier to diagnose the problem if you post a complete example: see How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: Hey, thanks - test is the variable name for the class I am calling the add method from, which the list view is in. The button which is calling the add method, is in a different scene/class.

Comment: I will try to create a minimal example aswell

Comment: Take a look at the little app I made here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969389/javafx-listview-chatting/40977656#40977656

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a global `ObservableList` name it for example `items`:

```
//create an ObservableList
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

---

Then use it in a way that every update on the `ObservableList` is reflected back to `ListView<String> manifestList;`

```
 manifestList.setItems(items);
```

---

**Now every time** you want to add a new item to the `ListView` add it on the `ObservableList`  . So you method can be modified to:

```
 public void addtoList(String manifestlist){ 
     items.add(manifestlist);
   }
```

---

Have a look at the links below:

[JAVAFX ListView chatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969389/javafx-listview-chatting/40977656#40977656)

and the tutorial from Oracle Bro's:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm

Comment: That's a great idea and i've implemented it, however it again doesnt seem to be updating the ListView within the scene gui.

However I print  ListView.getitems to console and the correct values are stored( name1 name2 name3) .. the same with the observable list.

Comment: @dan6657 Have a look at the comment of Sedrick Jefferson .The `ListView` is in sychronize with the values of `ObservableList`

Comment: @dan6657 You need to post a complete example in your question that demonstrates the problem. Otherwise people can only make blind guesses as to what you are doing wrong. If everything else in your code was correct, the code you have already posted would work. Create a [MCVE].

Comment: @dan6657 Edited the question and added extra links to tutorial so it is more clear to you what the mistake may be . Keep in mind that if nothing is wrong in your code that's the proper way of how to do this . If you are using external Threads to modify `JavaFX elements` you have to use `Platform.runLater();` [Just in case].