# Trying to add TextAreaInput to a scrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, jtextarea, scrollpane

I'm trying to make a GUI for a chat application. My GUI is quite simple yet, I want to put some functionalities before making it look more 'fancy'. So far it looks like this.[image]

What I basically want, is that when I press 'Enter' or click the button send,  it should append the input from TextArea, together with another string, and add it on the ScrollPane.

My code so far looks like this.

```
public class Controller {
@FXML
private TextArea textInput;

@FXML
private Button sendButton;

@FXML
private ScrollPane chatConversation;



public void initialize() {

    sendButton.setOnAction((event) -> {
        textInput.appendText("Button Action\n");
    });

}
```

And the FXML like this

```
<BorderPane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="1000.0" stylesheets="@style/style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <left>
      <Pane prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="184.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
   <center>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ScrollPane fx:id="chatConversation" prefHeight="734.0" prefWidth="816.0">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
              </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <HBox prefHeight="52.0" prefWidth="400.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="attach" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
                  <TextArea fx:id="textInput" focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="625.0" promptText="Write your message here" wrapText="true">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <effect>
                        <Glow level="0.06" />
                     </effect>
                  </TextArea>
                  <Button fx:id="emoji" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
                  <Button id="sendButton" fx:id="sendButton" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="70.0" textOverrun="CLIP" wrapText="true" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

I can add the textinput from Textarea to itself, and that worked, but when I'm trying to add that to the Scrollpane, it wouldn't work

Comment: How did you try to add the text to the scrollpane and why do you inject the `ScrollPane` but not it's content? You're trying to add the text to the  content of the `ScrollPane` after all.

Comment: Can you be more explicit if you don't mind? @fabian

Comment: ??? You don't add content incrementally to the `ScrollPane`-you add it to the content of the scrollpane. Also can you explain your non-working approach to adding text to the scrollpane?

Comment: Try replacing your `ScrollPane` with a `ListView`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969389/javafx-listview-chatting/40977656#40977656

Comment: @Sedrick thanks! I've used it after doing some research, and it works wonderful!