# Positioning labels in Hbox

Tags: java, javafx, hbox

[image]

`Labels` are positioning one by one in `HBox`. I want them to be one under each other. How can I make it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a `javafx.scene.layout.VBox`...? If you still want some sort of horizontal layout you could wrap certain `Label`s in certain `VBox`s and then add the `VBox`s to the `HBox`.

Comment: I used hbox, because it knows how enlarge label, if its content is big. And when i put label in vbox, it does not fit its size to the content of the label

Comment: get some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969389/javafx-listview-chatting

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put the VBox inside of the Hbox, then you can set the VBox to always grow with the HBox by setting the HBox.hgrow property to ALWAYS. If you do this, and set the prefWidth of the HBox to a size that at least fits your largest label then everything will be displayed.

Are you using FXML or Code? Can you post a snippet of what you have?

Comment: please explain how to place place label at center of hbox