# JavaFX TextFlow ScrollBar

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am creating small project in JavaFX. I created a TextFlow field to show messages i chat.

It looks good but,

[image]

When I add more messages this field does not make ScrollBar like TextArea.

[image]

I set max height in SceneBuilder but it does not work.

Is there way to create automatic ScrollBar like in TextArea ?

Comment: Wrap the `TextFlow` in a [`ScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html). Internally, a `TextArea` uses a `ScrollPane` as well.

Comment: I did not know it could. Works well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVAFX ListView chatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969389/javafx-listview-chatting)

Comment: Why not use the `ListView` node?

Answer (score 7):

it may some one comes here and looking for answer after one year of posting that question

the answer is

try to use Scene Builder the one that come with Netbeans just googl it and draw  first TextFlow  then click right and warp it with ScrollPane

or you can paste this code on you FXML

```
  <ScrollPane fx:id="sp" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="189.0" prefViewportHeight="148.0" prefViewportWidth="139.0" prefWidth="288.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="66.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0">
     <content>

              <TextFlow fx:id="pan1" prefHeight="193.0" prefWidth="276.0">


     </content>
  </ScrollPane>
```

Comment: This has to be the accepted answer although you missed `/` before closing tag `>` of `TextFlow`. Thanks